# cortana own command in backgroundtask

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, cortana

i am trying to write an c# programm to define custom commands for cortana!

First of all i create an default app-application and load the VCD file...

I create a second project link this to the main project and create inside this a backgroundtask to handle the cortana requests!

Now cortana know my commands, but if i tell her something she is answering "Es ist etwas schief gelaufen" (in english: "it fails").

I think the BackgroundTask is not correctly called.

App.cs

```
namespace CortanaCommandsStart
{
/// <summary>
/// Stellt das anwendungsspezifische Verhalten bereit, um die Standardanwendungsklasse zu ergänzen.
/// </summary>
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialisiert das Singletonanwendungsobjekt.  Dies ist die erste Zeile von erstelltem Code
    /// und daher das logische Äquivalent von main() bzw. WinMain().
    /// </summary>
    public App()
    {
        Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync(Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Metadata | Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsCollectors.Session);
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wird aufgerufen, wenn die Anwendung durch den Endbenutzer normal gestartet wird. Weitere Einstiegspunkte
    /// werden z. B. verwendet, wenn die Anwendung gestartet wird, um eine bestimmte Datei zu öffnen.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Details über Startanforderung und -prozess.</param>
    protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // App-Initialisierung nicht wiederholen, wenn das Fenster bereits Inhalte enthält.
        // Nur sicherstellen, dass das Fenster aktiv ist.
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Frame erstellen, der als Navigationskontext fungiert und zum Parameter der ersten Seite navigieren
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Zustand von zuvor angehaltener Anwendung laden
            }

            // Den Frame im aktuellen Fenster platzieren
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // Wenn der Navigationsstapel nicht wiederhergestellt wird, zur ersten Seite navigieren
            // und die neue Seite konfigurieren, indem die erforderlichen Informationen als Navigationsparameter
            // übergeben werden
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }

        try {
            StorageFile vcdStorageFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"LEDControll.xml");
            await VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync(vcdStorageFile);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("There was no error registering the Voice Command Definitions");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("There was an error registering the Voice Command Definitions", ex);
        }

        // Sicherstellen, dass das aktuelle Fenster aktiv ist
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wird aufgerufen, wenn die Navigation auf eine bestimmte Seite fehlschlägt
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Der Rahmen, bei dem die Navigation fehlgeschlagen ist</param>
    /// <param name="e">Details über den Navigationsfehler</param>
    void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wird aufgerufen, wenn die Ausführung der Anwendung angehalten wird.  Der Anwendungszustand wird gespeichert,
    /// ohne zu wissen, ob die Anwendung beendet oder fortgesetzt wird und die Speicherinhalte dabei
    /// unbeschädigt bleiben.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Die Quelle der Anhalteanforderung.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Details zur Anhalteanforderung.</param>
    private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
        //TODO: Anwendungszustand speichern und alle Hintergrundaktivitäten beenden
        deferral.Complete();
    }
}
}
```

Appxmanifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp">
  <Identity Name="32ed3ec5-2e4a-4517-ae2b-842653ab8a8e" Publisher="CN=Flo" Version="1.0.0.0" />
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="32ed3ec5-2e4a-4517-ae2b-842653ab8a8e" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>CortanaCommandsStart</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>Flo</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="CortanaCommandsStart.App">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="CortanaCommandsStart" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="CortanaCommandsStart" BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png">
        </uap:DefaultTile>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>

      <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService" EntryPoint="CortanaCommand.CortanaCommandService">
          <uap:AppService Name="CortanaCommandService" />
        </uap:Extension>
      </Extensions>

    </Application>
  </Applications>
</Package>
```

CortanaCommand.cs

```
namespace CortanaCommand
{
    public sealed class CortanaCommandService : IBackgroundTask
    {
        private VoiceCommandServiceConnection voiceServiceConnection;
        private BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral;

        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

            voiceServiceConnection.VoiceCommandCompleted += VoiceCommandCompleted;

            AppServiceTriggerDetails triggerDetails = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as AppServiceTriggerDetails;

            if (triggerDetails != null && triggerDetails.Name.Equals("CortanaCommandService"))
            {
                try
                {
                    voiceServiceConnection = VoiceCommandServiceConnection.FromAppServiceTriggerDetails(triggerDetails);
                    VoiceCommand voiceCommand = await voiceServiceConnection.GetVoiceCommandAsync();

                    // Perform the appropriate command depending on the operation defined in VCD
                    VoiceCommandUserMessage userMessage = new VoiceCommandUserMessage();
                    switch (voiceCommand.CommandName)
                    {
                        case "LedChangeColor":
                            var destination = voiceCommand.Properties["color"][0];
                            SendCompletionMessageForDestination(destination);
                            break;
                        default:
                            LaunchAppInForeground();
                            break;
                    }
                }
                finally
                {
                    _deferral.Complete();
                }
            }

        }

        private void VoiceCommandCompleted(VoiceCommandServiceConnection sender, VoiceCommandCompletedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (this._deferral != null)
            {
                this._deferral.Complete();
            }
        }

        private async void SendCompletionMessageForDestination(string destination)
        {
            // Take action and determine when the next trip to destination
            // Inset code here

            // Replace the hardcoded strings used here with strings 
            // appropriate for your application.

            // First, create the VoiceCommandUserMessage with the strings 
            // that Cortana will show and speak.
            var userMessage = new VoiceCommandUserMessage();
            userMessage.DisplayMessage = "Here’s your trip.";
            userMessage.SpokenMessage = "Your trip to Vegas is on August 3rd.";

            // Optionally, present visual information about the answer.
            // For this example, create a VoiceCommandContentTile with an 
            // icon and a string.
            var destinationsContentTiles = new List<VoiceCommandContentTile>();

            // Create the VoiceCommandResponse from the userMessage and list    
            // of content tiles.
            var response = VoiceCommandResponse.CreateResponse(userMessage, destinationsContentTiles);

            // Ask Cortana to display the user message and content tile and 
            // also speak the user message.
            await voiceServiceConnection.ReportSuccessAsync(response);
        }

        private async void LaunchAppInForeground()
        {
            var userMessage = new VoiceCommandUserMessage();
            userMessage.SpokenMessage = "Launching Adventure Works";

            var response = VoiceCommandResponse.CreateResponse(userMessage);

            // When launching the app in the foreground, pass an app 
            // specific launch parameter to indicate what page to show.
            response.AppLaunchArgument = "showAllTrips=true";

            await voiceServiceConnection.RequestAppLaunchAsync(response);
        }
    }
}
```

VCD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">

  <CommandSet xml:lang="de-de" Name="LEDControll">
    <CommandPrefix>LED</CommandPrefix>
    <Example>Steuere die LEDs</Example>

    <Command Name="LedChangeColor">
      <Example>LED Farbe grün</Example>
      <ListenFor>farbe {color}</ListenFor>
      <Feedback>Farbe wird geändert in {color}</Feedback>
      <VoiceCommandService Target="CortanaCommandService"/>
    </Command>

    <PhraseList Label="color">
      <Item> grün </Item>
      <Item> blau </Item>
      <Item> rot </Item>
    </PhraseList>

  </CommandSet>

</VoiceCommands>
```

Thank you, for your help!

Comment: Have you added your background task project as a referenced dependency of your startup project so that it gets deployed? Without it, nothing tells VS to actually deploy the background task.

Comment: Isn't it that lines:

      <Extensions>
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.appService" EntryPoint="CortanaCommand.CortanaCommandService">
          <uap:AppService Name="CortanaCommandService" />
        </uap:Extension>
      </Extensions>

Comment: No. The package manifest doesn't control Visual studio's build, linking and copying behavior. You want to go to the References part of your main startup project (the one that houses App.cs most likely), and add a reference to the background task project. The package manifest extension entry is just a mechanism that tells windows that there's a background service inside the app package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding the answer here so it's clear:

To ensure that the background task is added to the App Package properly, you can add a reference from the startup project to the background task project within VS:

1. Right click on references in the startup project
2. Go to Add Reference
3. Select "Projects" on the left
4. Tick the box next to the project containing the background task.
5. Hit OK.

This ensures that VS will build and copy the background task into the package when you go to deploy it. Otherwise, you run into difficult to debug problems like this.

Typically you can tell this has happened when you've triple-checked that the Package manifest uap:Extension entry has the right details, but can't get a breakpoint to hit in the background task when you try to activate it. I'll also check to see if there are any event log type entries that can be looked up to see this more easily.